# getBoundingClientRect() does not exist for safari on ipad. Workaround needed

Tags: javascript, jquery, ipad, safari

I just found out that getBoundingClientRect() is a great function and provides what i need (in order to calculate the line of my caret in a contenteditable div).
Unfortunatly the function does not exist for safari on ipad.
**What can i do to get the data getBoundingClientRect() provides?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you tagged it jquery, may I suggest looking at [`offset`](http://api.jquery.com/offset/)?

edit: I misread your question, so here some code to hopefully help you anyway:

http://jsfiddle.net/XyJ5r/1/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myid').keyup(function() {
        console.log('press');
        var sel = window.getSelection();
        console.log(sel);
        console.log(sel.focusOffset);
    });
});​
```

Comment: oh, i totally missed that caret. so, there is only text within that div?

Comment: +1 works, and i can detect the line number of my caret! thanks